# Export and import ssl certificate from cpanel to self manage hosting

Tags: ssl, nginx, cpanel

I have moved my server from cpanel managed hosting to nginx-centos server. I have only command line to manage my server. I need to export and import the ssl certificate. All the tutorials that I have found only explains "how to create open-ssl certificate on nginx server" for example here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-centos-6

This tutorial explains how to create it. If I copy the ssl private key and crt from cpanel and replace replace them with `/etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;` and `/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;` files will it work?

Answer (score 0):

ssl work with there files with cpanel
Cert
key
ca

like httpd.conf

```
SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/certs/xnh_com_d98c5_67ca3_150707$
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/keys/d98c5_67ca3_76c14a301e0260891bbe91504$
SSLCACertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/cabundles/cPanel_Inc__681917b
```

into nginx config

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
```

key file use it as same to /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key
for another one crt
enter that command

```
cat example.crt example.ca >> /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt
```